# Is it possible to auto allow usage of the microphone in chromium

Tags: chromium

I man using chromium-browser on raspbian. I was wondering if there was an easy way to auto allow the usage of the microphone. To stop the pop-up blocking one can use the switch `--disable-popup-blocking`. Sadly I haven't found a switch on [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). This list may be incomplete, so maybe I'm missing the switch I need.

To give more context: my home directory is on `tmpfs`. This means my preferences file is gone after every reboot. But it should be possible to just copy an old Preferences file into the `~/.config/chromium/Default/` directory right? I tried this already, then started the chromium-browser, but when accessing the site I was asked again if I would allow access to the microphone. It seems like the Preferences file just get overwritten on startup, it doesn't matter that it already exists.

I also tried starting chromium-browser so that it creates all the files including the Preferences file and replacing the `media_stream_mic` entry. But my guess would be that the preferences only get loaded on start so this does nothing.

So am I doing anything wrong? Or is there an easier way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was the missing `~/.config/chromium/First Run` file. If it doesn't exist the chromium-browser will create all the files anew, including the `Preferences` file which then gets overwritten. If it does exist only the missing files will be created. So copying a version of your `Preferences` File into `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences` and creating a the `~/.config/chromium/First Run` file will make this possible.

The bash script to do this automatically could look something like this:

```
mkdir /home/user/.config/chromium
mkdir /home/user/.config/chromium/Default
cp /somewhere/myOldPrefs /home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
touch /home/user/.config/chromium/First\ Run
chown -R user:user /home/user/.config/chromium
```

To insert more mic allowed pages one could use a simple `sed` command, it could look something like this:

```
sed -i 's/"media_stream_mic":{}/"media_stream_mic":{"https:\/\/\some\.page\.com:443,\*": {"expiration": "0","last_modified": "13271235276310223","model": 0,"setting": 1}}/' /path/to/the/Preferences
# this adds only one page when there are no pages yet
```